# Video (pulled from URL) doesn't display when attempting to place them in a list view with an Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-videoview

I'm trying to make a list view that displays videos from a URL but I'm getting nothing but a blank screen.

Here's  VideoPlayerActivity.java

```
package com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        String[] urls = new String[] {"http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4"};

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, urls);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Context context;
        private final String[] values;

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values){
            super(context, R.layout.movie_cell, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_cell, parent, false);
            final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start(); //need to make transition seamless.
                }
            });
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(values[position]));
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();
            return rowView;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Here's activity_video_player.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Here's movie_cell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The log message that I get when running the app is:

```
01-07 20:45:50.741    2367-2367/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-07 20:45:50.855    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
01-07 20:45:50.857    2367-2367/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0f3d30, tid 2367
01-07 20:45:50.865    2367-2367/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
01-07 20:45:50.929    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c4a040, tid 2382
01-07 20:45:50.946    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-07 20:45:50.972    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-07 20:45:51.028    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-07 20:45:51.028    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae0e88e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-07 20:45:51.623    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-07 20:45:51.623    2367-2382/com.example.nikhilbuduma.giflistview W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae0e88e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `VideoView`, use `ImageView` and get the thumbnail of the video.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(values[position], 
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing the trick, the thumbnails don't show. I think there's a deeper problem with the code I've written?